# JFree TimeSeries Chart Spanning Nanoseconds

Tags: java, datetime, jfreechart, time-series

I have to plot TimeSeries chart where the data is coming in nanoseconds. But, In my current implementation our date axis range is in Milliseconds.

**So how can I change the Date Axis range from milliseconds to nanoseconds.**

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer I gave on [your post](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116780) in the JFreeChart forum:

> The DateAxis won't give you precision below milliseconds, because
>   under the covers it is working with java.util.Date (which provides
>   only millisecond precision). I don't think there would be any obstacle
>   to creating a ValueAxis subclass that could handle nano-seconds, but
>   there is no implementation of that at present.